# Extracting layer from MODIS data in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-api

I am working with MODIS imageries in GEE and I am new to its interface. So I have been able to access the land cover product of MODIS (MCD12Q1). I have added imageries from 2003 uptil 2016. **How can i extract images of any particular year e.g. 2005 or 2010 in GEE for visualiztion?**. There is only one image per year in this product

Here is my code for fetching and displaying the collection:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
              .select('LC_Type1')
              .filterDate('2003-01-01','2016-12-31')
              .map(function(img){
                var d = ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start')));
                var m =ee.Number(d.get('month'));
                var y = ee.Number(d.get('year'));
                return img.set({'month':m,'year':y});
              });
//var igbpLandCover = dataset.select('LC_Type1');
var palette =[
  '1f8dff',//water
  '152106',//evergreen needleaf forests
  '225129',//evergreen broadleaf forests
  '369b47',//deciduous needleleaf forests
  '30eb5b',//deciduoud broadleaf forests
  '387242',//mixed deciduous forests
  '6a2325',//closed shrubland
  'c3aa69',//openshrubland
  'b76031',//woody savanna
  'd9903d',//savanna
  '91af40',//grasslands
  '111149',//permanenet wetlands
  'cdb33b', //croplands
  'cc0013', //urban
  '33280d', //crop/natural veg. mosaic
  'd7cdcc',//permanent snow/ice
  'f7e084', //barren/desert
  ].join(',');
Map.setCenter(100,15,6);
Map.addLayer(dataset,{'min':0,'max':17,'palette':palette},'IGBP classification');
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd do this is by filtering the `ImageCollection`. There are many way you could apply a filter in this case, I show you one way:

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
              .select('LC_Type1')
              .filterDate('2003-01-01','2016-12-31')
              .map(function(img){
                var d = ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start')));
                var m =ee.Number(d.get('month'));
                var y = ee.Number(d.get('year'));
                return img.set({'month':m,'year':y});
              });

var year = 2010

var filtered = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
var image = filtered.first()

var palette =[
  '1f8dff',//water
  '152106',//evergreen needleaf forests
  '225129',//evergreen broadleaf forests
  '369b47',//deciduous needleleaf forests
  '30eb5b',//deciduoud broadleaf forests
  '387242',//mixed deciduous forests
  '6a2325',//closed shrubland
  'c3aa69',//openshrubland
  'b76031',//woody savanna
  'd9903d',//savanna
  '91af40',//grasslands
  '111149',//permanenet wetlands
  'cdb33b', //croplands
  'cc0013', //urban
  '33280d', //crop/natural veg. mosaic
  'd7cdcc',//permanent snow/ice
  'f7e084', //barren/desert
  ].join(',');

Map.setCenter(100,15,6);
Map.addLayer(image, {'min':0,'max':17,'palette':palette}, 'IGBP classification '+year.toString());
```

[link to code editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/01d495ab668d48557406897e79e93d06)